Import Custom Properties to LibreOffice
I have a LibreOffice Writer document with about 20 custom fields.  For each new report, I need to open the custom property dialog and update each field.  Nice, but still time consuming when the data is readily available in a text file.
Is there a way to update the custom properties by some sort of import?  Thank you.

The UNO API provides access to custom properties, so a Python or Basic script could load and set them. This SO post shows code using the OooDev library that sounds like it might work for your case.

This is interesting, and I'm still trying to unpack it.  This py could run on any platform?  Here they are on Unix

I've written and run python-uno scripts on several different varieties of Linux. However, Unix systems such as Solaris or AIX generally don't have as much support for desktop software. If there are no builds with python scripting for your system, LibreOffice Basic will still work. If you try writing the code but get stuck, post the code you have so far either on StackOverflow or ask.libreoffice.org — it shouldn't be a difficult task for those of us who are familiar with UNO.
